# SQL JOIN using data from separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

I have a set of 3 tables(`tableA`, `tableB`, `tableC`).

`tableA` contains data for users' master account.
`tableB` contains data for users' sub accounts.
`tableC` contains purchase data for master account.

I am needing to do a `JOIN` statement originating with the sub account ID in `tableB`. I need to use that ID to locate the ID of the master account by referencing a column in `tableA`. I do not need this data in the output. Once I have the master account ID from `tableA`, I need to retrieve the purchase data in `tableC`.

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL statement without knowing the master ID and without outputting the data from `tableA`(master account data).

**To sum it up:** I have the sub account ID(`tableB`), need to look up the master account ID(`tableA`) and then return all of the purchase records stored by master account ID(`tableC`).

***EDIT:*** This is way easier than I was making it out to be(funny how taking a 5 min break fixes things...). The result was just a simple `JOIN` statement and only return the columns I needed.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Answer (score 2):

```
select B.field_1, C.field_3
from table B 
join table A on B.key_1 = A.key_1
join table C on A.key_2 = C.key_2
```